# Good answer with a link to company website

Tags: discussion, answers, advertising, external-links

Saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1022324/2006333).

It's a lengthy, descriptive and good answer.
The anonymous answerer has left a signature-kind of line at the end of Summary:

> For additional assistance, please do not hesitate to contact [BEC
>   Systems](http://bec-systems.com/) -- we're here to help.

Is this fine in Stack Overflow?

Comment: Are you sure that that is a good answer?  [think again](http://bec-systems.com/site/462/embedded-linux-versus-windows-ce) :P

Comment: @TheLostMind according to the dates on the linked blog post and answer they were posted on the same day. Is it possible it's not plagiarism, but rather the same user posting the blog and answer?

Comment: @DavidRobinson - Of course that's possible. But does the answer look like it is *tailored to answer what the OP asked*?

Comment: @TheLostMind Sort of hard to tell for me since the question is so generic/off topic? It's certainly about embedded Linux and Windows CE.

Comment: @TheLostMind Hmm. I didn't see that blog post :D